# Can't locate element using xpath in Eclipse

Tags: xpath

I use `firepath` due to locate element  and get `xpath` , but in `eclipse`, it does not work. Also Tried other variants referring to http://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html which also work in `firepath`, but `eclipse` they didn't find them like example 1

fragment of code:

```
<span class="registration ng-scope" translate="navbar_component.menuItems.sign_up" ng-click="$ctrl.goToPage('registration')" role="button" tabindex="0">Sign up</span>
<span class="registration ng-scope" translate="navbar_component.menuItems.sign_in" ng-click="$ctrl.goToPage('sign-in')" role="button" tabindex="0">Sign in</span>
```

That's what I have from `firepath`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sign-in']/span[2]/span[2]")).click();
```

(that's what fire path gave me)

Examples of my `xpath`
1

```
 .//*[@class='registration ng-scope']//following-sibling::span
```

I will be very grateful if you can advice me what I can use to locate `"Sign in"` button.

The exception received:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException:  Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700' System info: host: 'WS250', ip: '192.168.84.165', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, marionette=true, firefoxOptions={args=[], prefs={}}, appBuildId=20170125094131, version=, platform=XP, proxy={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, processId=2108, browserVersion=51.0.1, platformVersion=10.0, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=windows_nt}] Session ID: 14605620-ee13-4766-8edf-7b6cf31b35f6
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:274)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:84)
    at Selenium.test.SignIN.main(SignIN.java:14)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use text content of target element as:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Sign in']")).click();
```

You might need to wait until element is visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Sign in']")).click();
```

Comment: Any exceptions? Check whether this `span` located inside an `iframe`

Comment: My friend using python(ubuntu) and he can locate element with usual xpath given by firepath :(

Comment: `Firepath` could find element on page including all embedded `iframes` while `selenium` cannot... This might be `selenium`, but not `XPath` issue. Check whether element located inside an `iframe`. Also check updated answer

Comment: added exception in top

Comment: Try updated answer that should allow you to wait until target elemnt becomes visible. Also 1)check if element visible initially or you need to scroll down to it. 2) Is there only one `Sign In` button in page source (there also could be disabled buttons with same `HTML` code)

Comment: I missed to check with wait.until - yea it helped!

Comment: Please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it solved your problem. Thanks